# LoadRunner Replay issue of Javascript error

Tags: loadrunner

I have recorded a script on latest version vugen Web http/html protocol. While replaying that script I am getting Your browser doesnot support Javascript in replay window.

Comment: Turn off the runtime browser

Comment: If you require JavaScript execution in your front end, then see TruClient OR either a GUI Virtual User, A Citrix Virtual User, A Remote Desktop Virtual User operating against full browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime browser doesn't work like a GUI-based automation tool. It's used more of a guide to see the screens as it goes and can help with troubleshooting, so it doesn't render or work with Javascript.

This does not mean your test is not working, it just means that it can't process the javascript in that browser for you to run/view

As James mentions above, if you need to actually perform GUI-based testing of a web page, then the TruClient protocol is the better protocol to use (although substantially heavier resource consumption for your Load Generators)